# Is it possible to find $n-1$ consecutive composite integers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-set-theory, divisibility, factorial

Given an integer $n\geq  2$ ,can we always find an integer $m$  such that each of the $n-1$ consecutive integers $m+2,m+3,.....,m+n$ are composite?

Comment: Hint: If $k|m$, then $k|(m + k)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the numbers:
$$
k!+2,\,k!+3,\ldots,k!+k
$$
and you have $k-1$ consecutive composite integers.

Comment: If $k=2$ then how is $2!+3=5$ composite?

Comment: For $k=2$, you only have $2!+2=4$.

Comment: Oh yes thanks @DustanLevenstein

Comment: It is interesting to note this isn't at all minimal. Eg for $n-1=5$ we have $24, 25, 26, 27, 28$ but the recipe above says to look at 6!=720, 721, 722, 723, 724

Comment: If you replace $m=n!$ with the product of all primes $p\leq n$, you get something that still works, and still isn't minimal, but generally gives much smaller numbers than the factorial trick. For example, you can get five composites in a row with $m=2*3*5=30$, which gives us $32,33,34,35,36$.