# consecutive primes

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $n\in\mathbb N$. Prove that there are $n$ consecutive natural numbers that are not prime.
I tryed to use the fact about the factorization to product of primes and that there are infinite primes but I did not succeed. Any suggestions? thanks!

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1189697/prove-that-forall-n-ge-1-there-are-n-successive-non-prime-natural-numbers/1189703#1189703

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/982332/is-it-possible-to-find-n-1-consecutive-composite-integers

Answer (score 0):

If you can produce a number $n$ that has the primes $2$, $3$, $5$, and $7$ as factors, then the numbers $n+2$, $n+3$, $n+4$, $n+5$, $n+6$, and $n+7$ cannot be prime. Do you see why?

Try to generalize this argument to apply to an arbitrarily long list of numbers.